# Regex to match a listing

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to find a regex that will match a list pattern like:

```
A. banana
B. potato
C. apple
```

or

```
1. banana
2. potato
3. apple
```

even if the list doesn't start with `A or 1` like:

```
q. banana
r. potato
s. apple
```

can I get some help with this please?

EDIT: the regex should match only orders with alphanumeric characters, for example, this shouldn't get matched:

```
$. banana
&. apple
//or
b. banana
a. apple
```

Comment: You should explain your problem better. Are the items supposed to follow an order? And if yes, what rule determines this order? Is: `#. banana`, `$. potato`, `%. apple` also correct?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Ok, but the main problem is that a regex isn't able to consider orders (it doesn't know that "a" is before "b" or that "2" is before "3". There are workarounds to do that *(concatening a kind of alphabet at the end of the string and using a very complicated and inefficient pattern)*, but there are not reliable solutions.

Comment: All you can do is to use a more general pattern, something like: `/(?m)^([a-z0-9]+)\. .../i` and to check if items are consecutive using conventional code *(not a regex)*.

Answer (score 0):

use the following: `\w+(\.|\))\s.*`

This will match any line with a number or letter combination followed by a period. This will also match lists that use a `)` to separate the index and the item. The following will all match:

```
a. banana
b. potato
c. apple
1) banana
2) potato
3) apple
```